# How do I implement col-lg-10 col-lg-2 within a Bootstrap modal body?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

In the following code segment, I am trying to implement two side-by-side grids within a Bootstrap modal body, col-lg-10 and col-lg-2 but instead of appearing horizontally, the col-lg-2 is displayed beneath the col-lg-10.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="displayImageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-lg-10 text-center" id="modalDisplayImage">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/{{modalImage}}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2" id="productCards">
                    <div class="row" *ngFor="let image of displayImages">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="card">
                                <a (click)="setModalImage(image)">
                                    <img class="img-fluid card-img-top w-100 d-block" 
                                        src="assets/img/{{image}}">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#using-the-grid

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks.